# When a person gets a Mexican FMM online, when do they do the background check?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, mexico, fmm-tourist-card

If a person applies for a Mexican FMM online, will the background check be done immediately, and more importantly, before the FMM is made available to print out, and then at immigration you only have to get an entry stamp for validation and no further background check is done?

Or, is the FMM only filled out and paid for ahead of time when done online, and the actual background check is done when you present in person at immigration in Mexico?

Comment: Are you asking because you're concerned about the background check, or delays at immigration?  When I've been with people getting an FMM at the border (not done online) the entire process has been very quick, and I imagine any background check is just cursory automated and not in-depth or time-consuming

Comment: @Midavalo I'm asking because one of my travel partners may be denied entry into Mexico and if the background check is done beforehand when getting an FMM online, then maybe we would know if he will be allowed in ahead of time instead of getting turned around at the border?

Comment: due to something that occurred in Mexico, or elsewhere in the world?

Comment: @Midavalo Due to something in the US.

Comment: I would be very surprised if their background check checked anything outside of Mexico in the short timeframe between you asking for the permit and leaving with it

Comment: That said, if you are very concerned you could always apply for a Visa I guess and let them decide officially whether to allow you to enter or not

Comment: @Midavalo That's why I'm trying to find out if the background check is done ahead of time when applying for an FMM online. If so, that would avoid the possibility of getting to the Mexican border and having to turn our group around if one of our party is denied entry.

Comment: I do not believe Mexico will do a US background check when you visit. They might do a Mexico check, but unlikely to do an international check. See [How do countries access criminal information from foreign citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-do-countries-access-criminal-information-from-foreign-citizens) on [Expats.se] Stack Exchange

Answer (score 3):

I recently entered Mexico from the US by road at Tecate. Mexican Immigration wasn't present at the crossing, which was completely un-staffed. Leaving Mexico at the same crossing a few days later was the same.

While Mexican Immigration does look at my FMM and passport when I enter by air, and the airline collects the FMM on my way out, the border is not necessarily a fully-sealed boundary.

Thus, the question "When do they do the background check?" assumes a fact not always in evidence.